# Creating a custom decimal type for Protobuf

Tags: c#, .net-core, protocol-buffers

I have the following doubt:

I am following the implementation of a custom data type to support the decimal data type in gRPC communication following the microsoft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#creating-a-custom-decimal-type-for-protobuf

This is for the purpose of data in currency format since float and double are not accurate for this type of information.

The problem that I currently have is because I am making use of the options to generate the communication through rest:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package custom_type.v1;

option csharp_namespace = "CustomType.V1";

// Name "DecimalValue" prevents conflict with C# Decimal type
message DecimalValue {

    // Whole units part of the amount
    int64 units = 1;

    // Nano units of the amount (10^-9)
    // Must be same sign as units
    sfixed32 nanos = 2;
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "customTypes.proto";

message FooRpc {
   customTypes.DecimalValue price = 1;
}

message FindFooResponse {
  repeated FooRpc foo = 1;
}

rpc FindFoo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (FindFooResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/api/v1/foo"
    };
  }
```

Therefore, when making a request, the documentation and auto-generation of code when using the classes generated after compiling the proto.

It comes out like this:

```
{
  "units": 0,
  "nanos": 0
}
```

Even though it sent the data like this:

```
{
  "units": 200,
  "nanos": 990000000
}
```

The response I get is this:

```
{
  "units": "0",
  "nanos": 0
}
```

Payload:

```
PATH: /api/v1/foo
METHOD: POST
BODY:

{
   "price": {
      "units": 200
      "nanos": 990000000
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "price": {
      "units": "0"
      "nanos": 0
    }
}
```

The data is correctly stored in the database as the conversion is performed.
But when the data is sent to the client, it is reflected as mentioned above:

dotnet c# code

```
public override async Task<FindFooResponse> FindFoo(Empty request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new FooQueryRequest());

        // map handler response to grpc model
        return response.Adapt<FindFooResponse>();
    }
```

I would like to know if this behavior is normal, or what I am trying to do is not possible, or if instead there is a way to make the implementation and it is used in both gRPC and API.

Comment: question: are you *actually* using protobuf-net (tags), or are you using Google.Protobuf? it ... matters; also, can we see your DecimalValue message definition? finally: the payloads you're sending: are you sending JSON via gRPC web transcoding, or are you sending protobuf that you're *representing* in JSON for readability?

Comment: @MarcGravell Update the problem, I am using Rest which is where the problem occurs and I am using the classes generated by from the proto model for the api requests and responses.

Comment: In that case you aren't using Protobuf at all. You're showing the JSON output of a Web API which knows nothing about your custom decimal type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I don't know if I explained it well: D.

The api that I am working on has as input and responses the classes generated by FooRpc and FindFooResponse

Comment: @JoséRomero gRPC in aspnet has REST transcoding when using Google.Protobuf, so: it can be both

Comment: the last two payloads seem to be missing commas - is that actually the case, or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes correct, the same generated classes and types are used by both gRPC and api.

Comment: also: have you turned transcoding on? something like `services.AddGrpc().AddJsonTranscoding();`

Comment: @MarcGravell No, I don't think it applies to the version I currently have, which is netcore version 6.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding#versions-body-tab